# (KVM) virt-manager stuck in password prompt after open VM

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

so i installed a fresh ubuntu server 14.04 with KVM, i'm connecting with my other ubuntu machine using virt-manager.
so after i had permissions problem creating a new VM, i uncomment `user="root"` and `group="root"` in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf and it solved the problem.

but when i try open the graphical console of new VM with virt-manager it stuck in "user@ip" openssh password prompt, no matter how many times i type the password.

same issue with virt-viewer.

i might changed some permissions of folders when trying to solve the first problem. any clue?

p.s.
i did purge the libvirtd and reinstall everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem

in VM settings change display from "Spice server" to "VNC server" and it should fix the problem.

Issue is, that spice server only allows localhost connection by default. If you want to use spice, than you should change spice setting in hosting machine. Otherwise - use VNC.

Comment: No spice solution? Thats a workaround, not the solution....

Answer (score 1):

There's a better solution - as Philippe points out, the above is a workaround.

If you want to stick with "Spice server" as your display type, you can - just make sure to set "Address" = "All interfaces" instead of "localhost only".

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking for a solution to allow opening a guest virtual spice console from within ssh connected Virt-Manager.
For security, I refuse to let Spice listen on anything but localhost. Also I am occasionally doing this over the Internet, so everything needs to be in a ssh tunnel.

My current solution:
In the virt-manger ssh connection string I use a host alias that matches an entry in my .ssh/config. This makes it easy to include a localforward to the spice port on the host.  Alternately, could just open a second ssh connection.
Example connect string:

```
qemu+ssh://root@KVMHOST/system
```

Example .ssh/config

```
HOST KVMHOST
hostname 10.10.10.5
port 22
LocalForward 8900 localhost:5900
LocalForward 8906 localhost:5906

Host *
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Then, rather than opening the console from VMM, instead I open it from virt-viewer (or the gui version viewer) with spice://localhost:8906

This works great, except it's painful when using VMM to create a new guest, because in that case VMM tries to automatically open the viewer, and often when booting an ISO for install, we need to interact quickly to avoid some default, . Just need to plan ahead, selecting a specific spice port when creating the guest and adding the localforward to .ssh/config prior to connecting VMM to host.